# Template meta-programming: Wrong number of template arguments in Paramater Pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement a list using [Template meta-programming](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Template_metaprogramming) but without success compiling the next code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int Value>
struct Int {
    static constexpr int value = Value;
};

template<typename H, typename ...TT>
struct List {
    typedef H head;
    typedef List<TT...> next; // <-- Too few template arguments for class template 'List'
    constexpr static int size = sizeof...(TT) + 1;
};

int main() {
    typedef List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>> list1;
    static_assert(list1::head::value == 1, "Failed"); // = Int<1>
    static_assert(list1::size == 3, "Failed"); // = 3

    typedef typename list1::next list1Tail; // = List<Int<2>, Int<3>>
    static_assert(list1Tail::head::value == 2, "Failed");
    static_assert(list1Tail::size == 2, "Failed"); // = 2

    typedef typename list1Tail::next list2Tail; // = List<Int<3>> <<---error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
    static_assert(list2Tail::head::value == 3, "Failed");
    static_assert(list2Tail::size == 1, "Failed");

    std::cout << "Passed" << std::endl;
}
```

With an error:

```
In instantiation of ‘struct List<Int<3> >’: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
```

I understand that in my case `List` must handle two types `H` and `...TT`, but:

1. Why calling `List<TT...>` isn't enough?
2. How should I fix it?
3. What is the best approach in this case for compiling the code?

Comment: Think about what happens when `TT` is empty, you have `List<TT...>` but you need at least `H` to define least. You need a specialization for the end of the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last step `List<TT...>` will instantiate specialization `List<>` which is not defined in your code. You should write a "terminating" specialization as well:

```
template<typename H>
struct List<H> {
    typedef H head;
    typedef void next;
    constexpr static int size = 1;
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gCTEpwPIH2CYRwsi)

Comment: @DennisVash That really depends on the use cases for this template. I've just copipasted main template body, but always having both `head` and `next` nodes seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You need a specialization for an empty list or a list with a single element. One possibility is to first declare a fully variadic template, and then create two specializations:

```cpp
template <typename...>
struct List;

template <typename H, typename... TT>
struct List<H, TT...> {
    using head = H;
    using next = List<TT... >;
    constexpr static int size = sizeof... (TT) + 1;
};

template <>
struct List<> {
    constexpr static int size = 0;
};
```

This way you can have an empty list `List<>` which you cannot have with your current version.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a specialization for one element so you don't try to instantiate a `List` with an empty pack.

```
template <class H>
struct List<H>
{
    typedef H head;
    constexpr static int size = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant of the Holt's solution: instead of a second specialization, the ground case of the recursion can be the main template

```
template <typename...>
struct List
 { constexpr static int size = 0; };

template<typename H, typename ...TT>
struct List<H, TT...> {
    using head = H;
    using next = typedef List<TT...>; 
    constexpr static int size = sizeof...(TT) + 1;
};
```

Unfortunately is less readable.